# Randomly Moving a object using swing Component

Tags: java

I have created a square using swing components that moves right, left, up and down when clicked by buttons assigned to them. Now I am trying to move this object in a random fashion when clicked. This is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MovingObjects extends JFrame 
    implements ActionListener {

//    GUI code omitted here...

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private JButton button, leftButton,rightButton,upButton,downButton;
    private JPanel panel,redPanel;
    int x =10;
    int y=10;       

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MovingObjects frame = new MovingObjects();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.show();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);

    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        window.add(panel);

        redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redPanel.setLocation(x, y);
        redPanel.setSize(50, 50);
        panel.add(redPanel);


        leftButton = new JButton("Move Left");
        leftButton.addActionListener(this);
        window.add(leftButton);

        rightButton = new JButton("Move Right");
        rightButton.addActionListener(this);
        window.add(rightButton);

        upButton = new JButton("Move Up");
        upButton.setLocation(260, 60);
        upButton.setSize(100, 30);
        upButton.addActionListener(this);
        window.add(upButton);


        downButton = new JButton("Move Down");
        downButton.addActionListener(this);
        window.add(downButton);

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        //Move down
         if (event.getSource() == downButton)
            {
             if (y < 180){
             y=y+20;     
             redPanel.setLocation(x, y);

             }
            }
         //Move Up
             if (event.getSource() == upButton)  
             {
            if (y > 10){
             y=y-20;     
             redPanel.setLocation(x, y);
            }
             }
         //Move Left
             if (event.getSource() == leftButton)
             {
             if (x > 10){
             x=x-20;     
             redPanel.setLocation(x, y);
              }
             }
         //Move Right
             if (event.getSource() == rightButton)
             {
             if (x < 280){
             x=x+20;
             redPanel.setLocation(x, y);
                }
             }

    }


    }
```

Comment: When you say random fashion do you mean random units or random predefined direction. Also, there is no actual question here. Regardless, you will probably want to use java.util.Random in your code to generate a random number.

Comment: random defined directions. I was trying to implement the java.util.Random but unfortunately I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can us java.util.Random to generate an integer. If there were four possible directions then one might consider generating a random number between 1 and 4, inclusive, and then triggering the code to move in one of the four directions based on that, e.gl if 1 was generated you could trigger the code to move up, if 2 was generated then the code to move down, etc

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you expect.

1. I've added a new `JButton` called `randomButton`
2. You create an instance of class `Random()` - `rnd`**Don't forget to import *java.util.Random***
3. You define two variables (`xMax` and `yMax`) with your maximal x & y position limit. In your case it's the width of your `panel` minus the width of `redPanel` for `xMax` and same stuff with height for `yMax`.
4. You generate a random integer by calling the method `nextInt(int n)`
   , **BUT** the `nextInt(int n)` method returns following - *value
   between 0(inclusive) and n(exclusive)* , therefore we need to add
   `+1`
5. We set the location of `redPanel`

   ```
   //Move random
        if(event.getSource() == randomButton){
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int xMax = panel.getWidth()-redPanel.getWidth();
            int yMax = panel.getHeight()-redPanel.getHeight();
            x = rnd.nextInt(xMax+1);
            y = rnd.nextInt(yMax+1);
            redPanel.setLocation(x,y);
        }
   ```